# SqlException (0x80131904) with sitecore and sql server express 2016

Tags: iis, sitecore, sql-server-express

I'm getting the following sql exception when I try to connect to a newly installed sitecore instance (build worked), I am using SQL Server Express 2016.

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +1418
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +470
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +70
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +945
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +114
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1637
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +117
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +267
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +318
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +132
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +246
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand..ctor(IDbCommand command, DataProviderTransaction transaction, Boolean openConnection) +106
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.<>c__DisplayClass4.<CreateCommand>b__3() +48
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute(Func`1 action, Action recover) +289
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.<>c__DisplayClass12.<CreateReader>b__10() +30
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute(Func`1 action, Action recover) +289
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.CreateReader(String sql, Object[] parameters) +251
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.GetContentLanguages() +190
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.LoadLanguages() +146
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.GetLanguages() +49
   Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerDataProvider.LoadItemDefinitions(String condition, Object[] parameters, SafeDictionary`2 prefetchData) +1335
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.PrefetchItems(String itemCondition, String fieldCondition, String childCondition, Object[] parameters) +147
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.EnsureInitialPrefetch() +255
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.GetPrefetchData(ID itemId) +67
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.GetItemDefinition(ID itemId, CallContext context) +9
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.GetItemDefinition(ID itemID, CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers) +148
   Sitecore.Data.DataSource.GetItemInformation(ID itemID) +88
   Sitecore.Data.DataSource.GetItemData(ID itemID, Language language, Version version) +31
   Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.GetItemCommand.GetItem(ID , Language , Version , Database ) +92
   Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.GetItemCommand.Execute(ID , Language , Version , Database ) +496
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataCommands.GetItemCommand.DoExecute() +139
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() +96
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database) +292
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck securityCheck) +141
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.<>c__DisplayClass2f.<GetItem>b__2e() +58
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.ExecuteAndReturnResult(String pipelineName, String pipelineDomain, Func`1 pipelineArgsCreator, Func`1 fallbackResult) +96
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(String itemPath, Language language, Version version, Database database) +142
   Sitecore.FXM.Matchers.DomainMatcherRepository.GetAllDomainMatchers(IDatabase database) +81
   Sitecore.FXM.Sites.FxmSiteProvider.GetFxmSites() +182
   Sitecore.FXM.Sites.FxmSiteProvider.get_FxmSites() +103
   Sitecore.FXM.Sites.FxmSiteProvider.GetSites() +88
   System.Linq.<SelectManyIterator>d__16`2.MoveNext() +321
   Sitecore.Sites.SiteCollection.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 sites) +138
   Sitecore.Sites.SitecoreSiteProvider.GetSites() +225
   Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory.GetSites() +256
   Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext(String hostName, String fullPath, Int32 portNumber) +121
   Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver.ResolveSiteContext(HttpRequestArgs args) +430
   Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver.Process(HttpRequestArgs args) +50
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.(Object , EventArgs ) +528
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +142
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +92
```

From what I understand looking around at different other people who have similar problems the solution might be to go into my Sql Server Management Studio ->SQL Server network config and configure some protocols, however the UI for the SSMS for Express does not have the Network config as far as I can see, at least not under the connected database menu which has the submenus

Database
Security
Server Objects
Replication
Management

I would prefer to not have to get the non express installation, because I just need to check that frontend code I have developed when deployed into our Sitecore environment works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Sitecore compatibility tables here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164

Sitecore does not support SQL Server 2016 and it does not support SQL Server Express 2016.

Comment: technically speaking, damn.